# Issues using CGAffineTransform and UIPanGestureRecognizer together

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

I have a `view` that contains a `subview` that contains a pan gesture.  `subview` contains an additional `subSubview` that also has a pan gesture recognizer of its own.

view -> subview -> subSubview

Normally, both `subview` and `subSubview` pan without issue.

Then I perform:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.0, y: 2.0)
```

This also scales the `subview` and `subSubview` by 2.0

Now when I try to pan, the pan gesture method for `subview` continues to work perfectly.

However, the `subSubview` pan gesture now only gets picked up about 10% of the time.  I haven't been able to figure out any pattern as to what causes it to trigger those few times.

Additionally, the `subSubview` correctly picks up `touchesBegan` every single time, as it should, but again doesn't fire the pan gesture except for 1 out of ten tries.

As soon as I scale the `view` back down to 1.0 everything goes back to normal.

Any thoughts as to what is going on here and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the transform which scales the appearance of the view but doesn't actually change its bounds, try actually changing your width / height constraints (which is animatable) as this affects the actual bounds/size of your view which is what the gesture recognizer cares about.